# Redirecting from a page when not accessed via an iframe without using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, redirect, iframe

I need to redirect users if they try and access certain pages directly, i.e. not via the iframe I've provided. This is to stop them accessing other users' areas.

All the solutions I've found (which work, btw) use JavaScript - the current working script I have is

```
if (top == self) {
var newURL = 'http://www.exampleurlhere.co.uk/'
window.setTimeout('GotoIndex()',0);
}
function GotoIndex() { top.location.href = newURL; }
```

However, this will of course only work if the user has JavaScript enabled, which kind of scuppers me. Is there a way to achieve this server-side? I'm using aspx.

Thanks, Oli.

Comment: You could try looking at the requests received by the server both when accessing the page on its own and when loading it in an iframe, and see if there's any headers that distinguish the two. I don't know that there definitely would be though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - How would these appear different? A request is isolated.

Comment: @Oded As I said, I wasn't sure if there would be a difference; since apparently there isn't it's not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can't check it severside as IFrame requests (in general) are no different from any other HTTP request. You can however use a `GET` parameter to indicate this is an IFrame

```
<iframe src="mypage?iframe=yes"></iframe>
```

Obviously this solution will only work if you're in control of the code that contains the IFrame, otherwise there is no way to do it server-side.

Comment: There's nothing stopping me from including that parameter when *not* loading the page in an iframe, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Indeed there isn't. That's the only way I can think of that would help with the case at all - hence I suggested it. However if there was a solution based say, on headers, there would be nothing stopping you from forging a header, right? In fact as far as it goes for requesting page content you can imitate/forge a lot of things ;) (although I do see your point of having `?iframe=yes` as part of your normal coding or otherwise; certainly more probable than forging a request or such)

Comment: I think the question is trying to address the wrong problem. The user being able to load pages outside of an iframe isn't the overall issue, the fact that users can access information they shouldn't be able to is.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Possibly - what would you suggest? Honestly, I don't expect a lot of intentional snooping, I'm just trying to prevent accidental access.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Fair enough. Although tbf, if you need to use identifying iframe requests as access control, I think you're doing something wrong ;) But I see your point.

Comment: @OliJeffery If your users are required to log in you could at the very least check that the person logged in has access to the page they're requesting. If you're not expecting people to go intentionally searching for information they shouldn't be viewing, and there's nothing sensitive about the information they can see anyway, that may be enough.